How to Decide Between Using _input Events and _process Polling for Input Handling in Games
I am struggling to decide whether to handle input using events like _input or by checking input every frame, as in _process. I understand that the choice depends on the type of game being developed, but I would like to establish clearer criteria for making this decision.
For example, the following Godot documentation provides an example:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/input_examples.html

Events versus polling
Sometimes you want your game to respond to a certain input event - pressing the "jump" button, for example. For other situations, you might want something to happen as long as a key is pressed, such as movement. In the first case, you can use the _input() function, which will be called whenever an input event occurs. In the second case, Godot provides the Input singleton, which you can use to query the state of an input.

From this example, it seems to suggest that jumping should be handled with events, while movement should rely on polling. However, the documentation does not explain why this distinction is recommended.
What I’d like to understand is the reasoning behind choosing one approach over the other. Are there any general guidelines or best practices to help determine whether input should be handled through events or polling?
In addition to the above, there are multiple methods for checking input (such as is_action_pressed and is_action_just_pressed), which can quickly become confusing when considered in combination with events and polling.

I might be overthinking this, but when exactly are events processed?
Are they handled on a separate thread or something? Or are they processed after all the objects' _process functions have been executed in each frame of the game loop?
Or perhaps, is it something I don't need to worry about at all?

Button presses; etc. s/b "real time" (async) commands: they initiate an action or movement by the "AI"; unless the unit is busy. The frame is used to update progress as a result of those commands: firing / reciprocal firing; moverments; melees; dispersions;  pursuits. Calculations use "standard rates" of travel, loss, etc for a give interval (say  one minute), which are prorated based on the frame rate.  As for "holding" a key down, that is an "old" (modal) pattern. Today one "dispatches" a character on way (animation); and then has them turn; halt; jump ... using a "one click" command.

Thinking outside of Godot, event hooks into the underlying os can allow faster response to Input than any polling method constrained to an update interval. >300 fps vs 60? fps...

My general heuristic:
Polling for real time gameplay
I use polling in character controllers for action games where behaviour is rapidly changing and states are constantly transitioning with interpolated values. In these cases, I'm already using _process or _physics_process to update game state and it's generally simpler to include input handling alongside that code. I often want to react differently to taps vs holds and Input.is_action_just_pressed() Input.is_action_pressed() handles some of that state for me (detecting the initial press vs continued press). Also using Input.get_vector("move") applies a deadzone (for gamepads) and makes it so much easier than trying to get direction input with events.
See my long code sample in this jump answer for an example using both of these Input functions.
Events for turn-based behaviour
When creating widgets for turn based games or menu UI in action games, I use events. Allowing events to be consumed or bubble up reduces the global state I need to determine what part of the system should respond to which inputs.
See Viewport.set_input_as_handled() and Control.accept_event() and how they fit into InputEvent's How Does it Work steps. These functions don't affect Input functions above, so we need to set our real-time code to disabled when entering a menu.
Caveat
This works for me, but it's by no means absolute. Many developers will have other preferences or leanings.
